# Is there a visual difference between SGA, SXGA and UXGA video cables?

Tags: video, cable, vga

I've got a handful of VGA video cables. Is there a way to know which (if any) are UXGA cables? Is there a certain marking on the cable jacket I should look for, besides "UXGA" of course :) ?

Answer (score 4):

Although "VGA" technically means 800x600 resolution, the term "VGA cable" does not connote the resolution that the cable supports.

All your VGA cables should support UXGA (and higher) resolution.

Comment: 800x600 is actually SVGA; 640x480 is VGA